# MySQL UPDATE and JOIN ON the same column

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

`directory_country`

```
|country_id |iso2_code |iso3_code
|AD         |AD        |AND
|AE         |AE        |ARE
|AF         |AF        |AFG
|AG         |AG        |ATG
...
```

`customer_address_entity_varchar`

```
|value_id |entity_type_id |attribute_id |entity_id |value
|1        |2              |19           |1         |asdad
|2        |2              |20           |1         |Petya
|3        |2              |21           |1         |NULL
|4        |2              |22           |1         |Vasin
|5        |2              |23           |1         |asdasdasd
|6        |2              |24           |1         |asdasd
|7        |2              |26           |1         |KKK
|8        |2              |27           |1         |AFG
|9        |2              |28           |1         |American Samoa
|18       |2              |27           |2         |ARE
|35       |2              |28           |3         |Georgia
|36       |2              |30           |3         |123
|37       |2              |27           |3         |US
|38       |2              |31           |3         |133
```

I need to change `customer_address_entity_varchar.value` to the corresponding `directory_country.country_id` where `customer_address_entity_varchar.value` = `directory_country.iso3_code` and where `customer_address_entity_varchar.attribute_id` = 27.
This means to change ARE to AE, AFG to AF in the `customer_address_entity_varchar`.

I've researched Mysql Update tutorials and built query but it doesn't work and no errors shown.
Query

```
UPDATE `customer_address_entity_varchar` 
INNER JOIN `directory_country` 
  ON customer_address_entity_varchar.value = directory_country.iso3_code 
SET `value`= directory_country.country_id 
WHERE `attribute_id` = 27;
```

Thank you for your solutions.

Comment: And what is the Problem with your query?

Comment: Jens, Excuse me. It really works. There might be a problem with my PhpMyAdmin when I tested it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some trouble was in PhpMyAdmin, the query was correct. I will leave the correct answer here. May it will help someone.

```
UPDATE `customer_address_entity_varchar` 
INNER JOIN `directory_country` 
  ON customer_address_entity_varchar.value = directory_country.iso3_code 
SET `value`= directory_country.country_id 
WHERE `attribute_id` = 27;
```

Tutorial with clarification:
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-join/